# Error Updating Python3 pip AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, wsl-2

I'm having an error when installing/updating any pip module in python3. Purging and reinstalling `pip` and every package I can thing of hasn't helped. Here's the error that I get in response to running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` specifically (but the error is the same for attempting to install or update any pip module):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import CommandError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/home/patrick/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/patrick/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3268, in <module>
    _lib.OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests_unixsocket/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/home/patrick/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/patrick/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3268, in <module>
    _lib.OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import CommandError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/home/patrick/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/patrick/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3268, in <module>
    _lib.OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL. Python `openssl` is already installed.

```
sudo apt install python3-openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-openssl is already the newest version (19.0.0-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

My assumption is that I need to re-install some stuff, but I'm not sure what. I've tried the obvious stuff like `python3-openssl`, `libssl-dev`, `libffi-dev`, and `python3-pip` itself and `python3` alltogether.

Comment: How you are getting that error?

Comment: Sorry, I was getting it after running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. I'll update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: I found that this solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865819/how-to-install-python-cryptography-38-0-4-without-pip-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 148, accepted):

As version `39.0.0` presented this bug, downgrading the `cryptography` package solves this, without purging or touching your OS.

`pip install cryptography==38.0.4` to downgrade from `39.0.0` which presented this error

**EDIT** per @thomas,

The error is a result of incompatibility between `cryptography` and `pyopenssl`, so if possible, also upgrading to `openssl>22.1.0` should work:

```
pip install -U pyopenssl cryptography
```

Comment: More specifically, it seems to be an incompatibility between `cryptography` and `pyopenssl`, as mentioned here: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/7959.  Downgrading the former works, but even better probably to upgrade openssl to `>22.1.0` (if not in version conflict with other dependencies).

Comment: to upgrade both: `python3 -m pip install -U pyOpenSSL cryptography`

Comment: How can I downgrade cryptography, the pip command itself not working? throwing the same error message as mentioned.

Comment: Upgraded pyopenssl to 22.1.0, cryptography was automatically downgraded to 38.0.4 and conda now works fine.

Comment: @sovon See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75865819/how-to-install-python-cryptography-38-0-4-without-pip-on-ubuntu ; download cryptography-38.0.4-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl  from https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/38.0.4/#files

Answer (score 20):

Another solution would be to simply pip remove the pyOpenSSL and then install it again:

```
pip uninstall pyOpenSSL
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Answer (score 0):

> **DANGER: This solution is only suitable for Ubuntu in WSL.
> It's what I run, but follow-up from other users has confirmed that it can completely break any installed desktop environment.**

What I needed to do was to purge the apps, *and* delete `~/.local/lib/python3.8`. This was the step that I'd been missing.

So in the end, the fix was:

```
sudo apt purge python3 python3-pip python3-openssl
rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python3.8
sudo apt install libssl-dev libffi-dev python3 python3-pip python3-openssl
```

Then, I could run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` without error.

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for the answer! Can you mark it as an answer? For future occurrences accepting answers (even your own ones): [How can I accept an answer and which one should I choose?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/17355758)

Comment: don't follow this answer on ubuntu. As it uninstalls many desktop apps including gnome. it created a lot of trouble for me

Comment: Handle with care! This answer is very dangerous! Since you remove python3, you will also remove ALL the packages relying on it, i.e. MOST of your computer packages. I do not recommend it!

Comment: DON'T DO THIS IF YOU ARE ON A SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

first :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then :

```
pip install -U pyopenssl cryptography
```