# How to install python cryptography 38.0.4 without pip on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, pypi

My pip has corrupted after trying to install Apache Airflow. Every time I am trying to use it I am getting the following message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import CommandError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/home/bill/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/bill/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 3268, in <module>
    _lib.OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75053968/9758352) answer, I need to downgrade cryptography. However I cannot do it using pip since I am getting the same error. I tried to download to my Ubuntu the `wheel` file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/38.0.4/#files); specifically `cryptography-38.0.4-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl`. However, when I extracted it, there was no `setup.py` file inside it. The only way I can imagine installing it without using pip is moving the extracted files to the place python libraries are stored. However I cannot find the place where the old cryptography library was installed.

How to install the specific version on my machine without using pip and considering there is no `setup.py` file?

Comment: Edit the `crypto.py`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73932621/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+%22module+lib+has+no+attribute+OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms%22

Comment: @phd Removing the line causing the error does not solve the problem. It causes the next line to raise an error. Removing the next line doesn't help either.

Comment: @pdh Also, in the list of posts you provided the problem is solved mostly by using pip upgrade or something similar, but I am unable to use it.

Comment: Try creating a fresh venv and install the dependency into that one https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: @JorgeRuiz This is a solution because I can work inside a virtual environment, however I don't know how to solve the problem with the "global" `pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out where old cryptography library was installed using:

```
python3 -c "import cryptography; print(cryptography.__file__)"
```

I deleted the folder and pasted the cryptography version 38.0.4 that I had downloaded from the link above.

Comment: What "link above"?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the link at the original post (https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/38.0.4/#files)